# Angular 2 *ngIf true -> render button

Tags: javascript, angular, web

On my site I have two buttons, next and previous to navigate between newer (next) and older (previous) items of news. I wish to prevent the next button being rendered on the page when there is no newer news available to view. To do this I used *ngIf

```
<a *ngIf="isNextNews()" (click)="nextNews()">&#60; Next</a>
```

Here is the function to check for more recent news:

```
public isNextNews() {
        this.findNewsInCategories();
        if(typeof this.appConfigService.news[this.newsIndex-1] == 'undefined') {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

This works, but not quite as well as I'd hoped. Instead of the next button always being rendered and only being removed when the check fails it re-renders every time you navigate to a newer or older news item.
The functionality I'm looking for is having the next button always be rendered except for when the check fails, removing the next button from the DOM.
Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Comment: Are you using a router to navigate?

Comment: Yes: this.router.navigate([this.localize.translateRoute('/news/'+this.appConfigService.newsCategorySelected+"/"+prevNews.slug)]);

Comment: It sounds like the news could be a child route, and the navigation buttons could be in a parent route so they stay put.

Comment: I want it to stay put but the issue is it doesn't as soon as I add *ngIf to it. The previous button stays put but the next button re-renders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use functions in template expressions (in this case `*ngIf`), that is because the function will be called after each change detection. Use a variable instead.

```
hasNextNews:boolean = false; //use this in your view
constructor(){
}

nextNews(){
  //your logic
  this.isNextNews(); //added
}

isNextNews() {
   this.findNewsInCategories();
   this.hasNextNews = (typeof this.appConfigService.news[this.newsIndex-1] != 'undefined')
}
```

Html:

```
<a *ngIf="hasNextNews" (click)="nextNews()">&#60; Next</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you're calling `loadNews()` on first page load, then it should be like

```
var hasNextNews = false;
public loadNews() {
   ## load your current news here
   isNextNews();
}
```

and next function:

```
public isNextNews() {
    this.findNewsInCategories();
    if(typeof this.appConfigService.news[this.newsIndex-1] == 'undefined') {
        this.hasNextNews = false;
    }
    this.hasNextNews = true;
}
```

html:

```
<a *ngIf="hasNextNews" (click)="nextNews()">&#60; Next</a>
```